# Quels sont les pangrammes les plus courts?

Tags: jeux

Un pangramme est une phrase comprenant toutes les lettres de *a* à *z*.

Par exemple : « *Perchez dix, vingt woks ; qu’y flambé-je ?* » est un pangramme de 30 lettres.

Connaissez-vous des pangrammes plus courts, ou bien des pangrammes avec toutes les lettres : aâàæbcçdeéèêëfghiîïjklmnoœôpqrstuùûüvwxyÿz
(éventuellement ö).¹

--

Notes

1. Cette liste de lettres du français vient des [petites leçons de typographie](http://jacques-andre.fr/faqtypo/lessons.pdf) de Jacques André.

Comment: Hum, c'est quoi les règles ? Ça doit être grammaticalement correct. Ça doit avoir un sens ? Pour cet exemple, j'ai du mal à trouver un contexte complet, mais je comprend qu'on puisse flamber des choses dans un wok.

Comment: Ce type de question demandant une simple énumération trouve d'habitude une réponse plus qu'exhaustive sur [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangramme)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puisque tu cites J. André, impossible de ne pas référencer [la lettre de GUTenberg de février 1994](http://www.gutenberg.eu.org/IMG/pdf/lettre2.pdf), qui fait quelques propositions. De Rozenn et Gaëlle Le Petit :

> Ça, quel cafarnaüm d'ægipan ! Dépôt de whisky et xérès à l'île du jazz où vivait le maïs âpre, bien qu'il fût au cœur de la forêt.

De Jean Robert, deux propositions, une avec un `æ` et une sans :

> Dès Noël, à Aÿ giboyeux où qu'œil fût, j'ai rêvé ça : Ésaü, aîné haï, ôtez de l'æthuse ce kiwi pâmé !
>   Dès Noël, à Aÿ giboyeux où qu'œil fût, j'ai rêvé ça : Ésaü, aîné haï, ôtez ce kiwi pâmé !

D'Emmanuel Saint-James, une épigramme :

> À l'île exiguë
>   Où l'obèse jury mûr
>   Fête l'haï volapük,
>   Âne ex aéquo au whist,
>   Ôtez ce vœu déçu.

Il y a aussi celui qu'il cite souvent

> Dès Noël où un zéphyr haï me vêt de glaçons würmiens
>   je dîne d’exquis rôtis de bœuf au kir à l’aÿ d’âge mûr
>   & cætera !

et qui si j'ai bonne mémoire provient du même concours.

Answer (score 5):

[Cette page](http://www.fatrazie.com/pangramme.htm) en liste plusieurs beaux, notamment un de vingt-neuf lettres

> Whisky vert : jugez cinq fox d'aplomb

Il y en a jusqu'à vingt-six lettres mais moins élégants

> Jyck : Vingt rumbs, zed, waqf, phlox

Comment: Tiens, c'est amusant, j'avais retenu _Portez ce whisky au vieux juge blond qui fume_ mais on dirait que c'est le whisky qui est vieux, pas le juge. Enfin, tant que ce n'est pas le whisky qui fume...

Comment: (+1) pour l'humour absurde du second.

Comment: Aix, c'est lent, rend, voix !

Answer (score 3):

> Film X prêt : gadjo, whisky, buvez cinq.

(29 lettres)

Answer (score 3):

Avec 26 lettres :

JT : Voyez DSK furax. PQ WC HLM bing !