# Comment appelle-t-on des vers rimant entièrement ?

Tags: poésie, jeux

[Cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/767/quels-sont-les-pangrammes-les-plus-courts) m'a rappelé un jeu dont j'avais entendu parler à l'école :  des vers rimant entièrement, l'exemple était

> Par les bois du Djinn où s'entasse de l'effroi
>   Parles, et bois du gin, ou cent tasses de lait froid

Comment appelle-t-on ce jeu ? En connaissez-vous d'autres ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ce sont des vers [holorimes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vers_holorimes).

Les vers que tu cites sont d'Alphonse Allais. Il n'était pas le premier.

> Ô, fragiles Hébreux ! Allez, Rebecca, tombe !
>   Offre à Gilles zèbre, œufs. À l'Érèbe hécatombe ! (*[Victor Hugo](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Hugo)*)
>
> Gall, amant de la Reine, alla, tour magnanime,
>   Galamment de l'arène à la tour Magne, à Nîmes. (*[Marc Monnier](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Monnier)*)

Le mot semble s'être répandu du français vers d'autres langues, non seulement l'[anglais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holorime) mais même jusqu'au [japonais](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holorime).

Comment: En japonais, c'est quand même beaucoup plus simple… Je n'irai donc pas jusqu'à dire « même jusqu'au japonais. » Et puis le lien wikipedia japonais ne cite même pas d'holorime en japonais, se contentant d'exemples en français et anglais.

Answer (score 10):

On appelle ces rimes "[Vers holorimes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vers_holorimes)":

> "*Des **vers holorimes** ou **olorimes** sont des vers entièrement homophones; c'est-à-dire que la rime est constituée par la totalité du vers, et non pas seulement par une ou plusieurs syllabes identiques à la fin des vers comme dans la rime « classique ».
>
>   Cette figure de style est ancienne, mais le premier sonnet recensé entièrement constitué d'holorimes est l'œuvre de Jean Goudezki (1866-1934)*"

Answer (score 3):

J'improvise :

> Par les portes offrant ses idéaux sibyllins,
>   Parle et porte au français idées aussi bilingues.

Comment: Euh... celui-ci marche... à condition de prononcer le premier vers avec un fort accent marseillais.

Comment: J'ai oublié de préciser que je suis né toulousaing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

La question a déjà eu sa réponse (un vers holorime), mais comme d'autres exemples sont demandés, en voici un :

> L'Arable Ali est mort au lit.
>   Moralité : Maure Ali, t'es mort alité.

```
Moralité :
Maure Ali, t'es
Mort alité
```

Answer (score 0):

> Laurent Pichat virant, coup hardi bat Empi
>   Lors Empi chavirant, couard, dit « bah, tant pis »

Serge C